# Adobe Illustrator SVG external font embedding

Tags: php, svg, font-face, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to generate a SVG file with PHP but after saving and opening the file with Adobe Illustrator, I get this error:

```
The document uses fonts or characters which are not available or are in a different format than originally specified

myfont:
An unknown problem occurred.
```

Here's the SVG code

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="30cm" height="10cm">
    <defs>
        <style>
        <![CDATA[
        @font-face {
            font-family: "myfont";
            src: url("base.ttf") format('truetype'); /* in the same directory */
            }
         ]]>
        </style>
    </defs>
    <text x="1cm" y="3cm" fill="red" font-family="myfont" font-size="2cm">It works</text>
</svg>
```

[Output in browser](http://prestalife.net/tests/svg/test.svg)
It's working fine in browser but not in AI

I also tried the absolute ttf url as well as base64 encoding

```
url(data:font/ttf;base64,AAEA… )
```

What am I missing and what could be preventing AI from using the font file/data

Comment: Lack of support for web fonts perhaps?  Remember AI isn't a native SVG editor.  It's main priority w.r.t. SVG will be (1) trying to export SVG files that match the AI files as well as possible (2) have a reasonable SVG import feature that supports most files.  It is not really that surprising that it doesn't support every SVG feature perfectly - or all the latest CSS3 features.

Comment: @BigBadaboom Thank you, I will just tell clients to install the fonts on their system and then generate the SVG without embedding